# create public url to view in portlet

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, liferay, liferay-6, jsf-2.2

I have simple primefaces portlet, which is connected to the database. I have view (index.xhtml) with the table, which presents all my entries from db (I'm using p:dataTable). I have also a simple view (someView.xhtml), which shows specific information about one selected entry. When I click in the table one entry, browser loads someView.xhtml and page url looks like this:

```
somepage?p_auth=wRR1tGze&p_p_id=SomePortlet&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_SomePortlet__facesViewIdRender=%2Fviews%2Findex.xhtml
```

I need to create url which directly shows me page someView.xhtml and get custom parameter from url.

I'm using primefaces 3.5 and liferay 6.2 with bridge 3.2.4.

Thanks in advance.
Marcin

Answer (score 2):

Liferay Faces Bridge has a Facelet implementation of the portlet: JSP tags.

Not sure if that's what you are asking for, but you can do a full page HTTP GET by putting something like this in your facelet view:

```
<ui:composition xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
     xmlns:portlet="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0">
    <portlet:renderURL var="renderURL">
        <portlet:param name="_jsfBridgeViewId" value="someView.xhtml" />
    </portlet:renderURL>
    <h:outputLink value="#{renderURL}" />
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but renderUrl is empty string. I tried use it with f:view also.

Comment: Here is a [working example](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-faces/blob/master/demos/showcase/showcase-portlet/src/main/webapp/component/portlet/renderurl/general/renderURL.xhtml) from the Liferay Faces Showcase